# Accessing nodejs functions inside expressJs static HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm a Javascript and Nodejs newb and I'm not sure how to best organize things. I'm writing a web interface for a C++ application by using Nodejs and V8 convert to wrap a C++ API. The question I have is, is there some way I can use Express to serve HTML that has references to functions/global inside nodejs? Or do I have to resort to having a bunch of res.write(html) types of calls in the HTML in order to do that?

For example, I want to prefill form data with stuff that's accessed from a C++ configuration API. The C++ API is wrapped in a Nodejs module. Right now anything that needs to be dynamically generated (like prefilled forms) I just do something like,

```
var novaconfig = require('./NodeAppConfig/build/Release/appconfig');
var AppConfiguration = new Appconfig.AppConfigBinding();

var express=require('express');
var app = express.createServer(express_options);

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(app.router);
    });


app.get('/configureApplication.html', function(req, res) {
    console.log("[200] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
    res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<HTML>');
    res.write('<HEAD>');
    res.write(' <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="configstyle.css" media="screen">');
    res.write('</HEAD>');
    res.write('<BODY>');

    res.write('<label>');
    res.write(Interface);
    res.write('</label>');
    res.write('<form method="post" action="/configureNovaSave">');
    res.write('<input type="text" name="interface" value="');
    res.write(AppConfiguration.GetCurrentInterface());
    res.write('" /><br />');

    res.write('<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton" value="Save Settings" />');
    res.write('</form>');
    res.write("<br/>");
    res.write('</BODY>');
    res.write('</HTML>');

    res.end();
});
```

But this is obviously a bad way to do it. Is there a way to have the dynamically generated HTML in a stand alone file and then still access AppConfiguration.GetCurrentInterface() within it? What's a good way to organize the files for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a template engine. Maybe take a look at Jade or Mustache. Then you just pass in the parts you want to be dynamic and the engine renders the page for you.

Answer (score 1):

The code would look something like the following

```
app.get('/configureApplication.html', function(req, res) {
    var config = AppConfiguration.GetCurrentInterface();
    res.render('configureApplication.jade', {locals: {config: config}});
});
```

configureApplication.jade can access the variable 'config' as follows

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= config
```

Full documentation here

http://jade-lang.com/

Comment: Well, I was hoping for something a little more PHP like where I could just refer to some serverside Javascript inline in the HTML doc. Jade is working alright, but it's a pain to have to pass all of the arguments I want to use to the template.